# Why is my synchronous code using setTimeout behaving asynchronous in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, timeout, qunit

I'm trying to loop 10x over a test (waiting for the condition to be true), but somehow it's not working.

Here is what I have:

```
// my counter
$.testHelper.countDown = function(test, iteration) {
    var ticker = iteration || 0;
    if (ticker > 10) {
      return false;
     }
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if (test === true) {
            console.log("SENDING");
            return true;
        }
        ticker += 1;
        $.testHelper.countDown(test, ticker);
     }, 1000);
    };

    // my test     
    $.testHelper.testForElement = function(element) {
        var result;   
        console.log($i.find(element).length > 0); // true
        result = $.testHelper.countDown(
             $i.find(element).length > 0
        );
        console.log(result);  // undefined
        return result;
     };
```

My problem is that although my condition equates to `true` before I'm calling countdown, the answer from countDown is `undefined`. So my logs come in like this:

```
// true - before firing my countDown method
// undefined - should not log
// SENDING - response from countDown (= true)
```

**Question**:
From the code displayed, is there a reason, why my `undefined` is logged before `countDown` is through and returns `true`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erm, because `setTimeout` is *always* asynchronous? That's kind of the whole point.

Here's a possibility for you:

```
function when(condition,then) {
    // condition must be a callback that returns `true` when the condition is met
    if( condition()) then();
    else setTimeout(function() {when(condition,then);},1000);
}
```

This will poll once every second until the condition is met, and then do whatever is given in the `then` callback.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, so... no, sorry!

Comment: I'm waiting for an element "to show up" (= be generated) so I want to loop 10x and check if it's there.

Comment: you may have to use a callback

Comment: @frequent well `setTimeout()` returns immediately. The function you pass it will be called when the timer expires. Thus, you need to put code *inside* the timer handler if you want it to happen after some time has elapsed.